# How to send personalised emails to people who share the same email address?

Tags: mailgun

Does anyone know how I can send emails to the same email address but personalised to different people?

I'm batch sending personalised emails using Mailgun's API. 
The 'To' header contains a comma separated list of email addresses e.g.

```
aa@hotmail.com, bb@hotmail.com, cc@hotmail.com
```

and the 'recipient-variable' header contains the JSON linking email addresses with the personalised data eg

```
recipient-variables={
                     "aa@hotmail.com": {"salutation":"Fred Bloggs"},
                     "bb@hotmail.com": {"salutation":"Sally Smith"},
                     "cc@hotmail.com": {"salutation":"John Doe"}
                    }
```

All works fine until I have two (or more) people who share an email address eg

```
To header:  aa@hotmail.com, bb@hotmail.com, bb@hotmail.com

Recipient variable header:
recipient-variables={
                         "aa@hotmail.com": {"salutation":"Fred Bloggs"},
                         "bb@hotmail.com": {"salutation":"Sally Smith"},
                         "bb@hotmail.com": {"salutation":"John Smith"}
                        }
```

Mailgun generates the same message ID for all emails when using batch *(incidentally violating section 3.6.4 of RFC2822)*, so although Mailgun's event logs show two emails are sent and delivered to address bb@hotmail.com, only one, it seems to be the last one defined in the JSON, i.e. John Smith, is ever shown in the email client, with the first one being discarded or overwritten.

I get the same result with duplicate addresses sent to several different ISPs and to people using several different email clients so it does not seem to be recipient specific.

*BTW I did investigate mailing lists and templates instead but it seems impossible to create a mailing list with any duplicate addresses, trying to add an address that already exists gives an error.*

Comment: it looks like an edge case not considered by devs. Probably needs a workaround, e.g. scheduling duplicates to next batch.

Comment: My workaround at the moment is to first count the maximum number of  duplicates and then generate the email body, and the recipient-variable JSON with enough variables to cover the max eg `"bb@hotmail.com": {"salutation1":"Sally Smith","salutation2":"John Smith" }` and have empty strings for the unused variables sent to non duplicates. A bit messy though. You idea could work if I first collect all the duplicates and do a second (or third etc.) batch send. Mailgun's support is pretty useless as they never seem to read the question and often simply point you to the documentation.